# C# compare two string arrays

Tags: c#, string-comparison

I've got two files

"Database.txt" contains the following names:

1. Dog
2. Cat
3. Mouse
4. Panda
5. Bear

"Slave.txt" contains the following names:

Cat
Panda

I want to compare the "Slave.txt" with "Database.txt" and create third file with:

```
2. Cat  
4. Panda
```

(Cat and Panda from Slave.txt find in Database.txt)

My code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String directory = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\";
        String[] linesA = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "Database.txt"));
        String[] linesB = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "Slave.txt"));
        IEnumerable<String> onlyB = linesB.Intersect(linesA);
        File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "Result.txt"), onlyB);
    }
```

works only on Database.txt structure like:

Dog
Cat
Mouse
Panda
Bear

without line numbers.
Is there somethink instead .Intersect to find only part of string, not full string?

Comment: Do you want to match also "12. Blue Panda" with "Panda"?

Comment: Just write a loop.  Or if you really want to use linq, a `.Where(predicate func)`

Comment: As a second parameter the function .intersect allows you to put in a customer equalitycomparer on which you can decide how to compare your objects. Using this equality comparer you can make an equasion on string.contains(otherString) for example. Or even easier: Use jasonw's suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple approach is with `Any` from Linq. It is only checking if any part of a line in B is contained in any line of A no matter the case.

```
var onlyB = linesA.Where(a => linesB.Any(b => a.ToLower().Contains(b.ToLower())));
```

Note: Updated to shows lines from A instead of lines from B.

Comment: It still shows me in Result.txt: "Cat Panda" not "2. Cat 4. Panda"

Comment: Sorry, must have misread your question. I thought you wanted the B lines instead of the A lines, but no big deal. Just updated answer to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Linq like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String directory = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\";
        String[] linesA = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "Database.txt"));
        String[] linesB = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "Slave.txt"));
        IEnumerable<String> onlyB = linesA.Where(x=>linesB.Contains(x.Substring(x.IndexOf(". "+1))));
        File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "Result.txt"), onlyB);
    }
```

Comment: Try this again I changed somethings

Comment: A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Additional information: StartIndex cannot be lower then zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a test method that I wrote and tested:

```
private string[] Matcher()
{
    string[] file1 = { "1. Dog","2. Cat","3. Mouse","4. Panda","5. Bear" };
    string[] file2 = { "Cat", "Panda" };
    string[] file3 = file1.Where(d => {
        foreach(string matcher in file2)
        {
            if(Regex.Match(d, @"^\d+\.\s+"+matcher + "$").Length > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }).ToArray<string>();            

    return file3;
}
```

I suppose you have line or item numbers before the records on file1. This will try to match for : a number combination, a dot and the desired values with a regular expression, and when it matches an element on the list, it'll take that element to the `file3` array.

And it will discard **Sabre Cat** when you are searching only for **Cat**.